# NetBeans Starting of Tomcat failed

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, jprofiler

I have installed JProfiler yesterday. And integrated it with NetBeans. And after this I cannot run project, so I decided to uninstall JProfiler. But now I can see messages in the error log, see below. Why NetBeans still looking for **jprofilerti.dll**? How can I handle this error?

Messages:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\apache-tomcat-7.0.41.0_base"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\apache-tomcat-7.0.41.0_base\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library C:\PROGRA~1\JPROFI~1\bin\WINDOW~1\jprofilerti.dll in absolute path, with error: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate `setenv.bat` in %CATALINA_BASE%/bin or %CATALINA_HOME%/bin and remove the line that adds the -agentpath VM parameter to the JAVA_OPTS environment variable.